# ASP.NET UI Generation

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, code-generation

I'm Looking for some samples (will be better if they are open source) that enabling Programmer to Generate UI from Database.
I want to review them for the framework that i want to develop for myself.
Already i reviewed ASP.NET Dynamic Data and Nettiers.
Also i welcome your suggestions , tips , comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at a project I'm about to release, [CodeGenerator](http://thecodegenerator.com/). There is a [sample project](http://thecodegenerator.com/Sample-CS) which illustrates how you can use CodeGenerator to quickly generate an entire administrative site. Have a look and let me know your thoughts.

BTW, this is just a small example of what CodeGenerator can do.

Comment: Not yet - soon! (Should be within a week.) I'll post here when there is. If you're interested in working with a preview/beta version, send us an email as indicated on the site (linked above).

Comment: Thank You. I will, don't forgot to link demo / final version here !

Comment: FYI CodeGenerator has been released! You can get a demo version here: http://www.quantumconceptscorp.com/Products/CodeGenerator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

While perhaps not directly what you may want, have a look at Entity Framework Code First to let the code drive the DB model and it works well with existing databases.

Then with MVC you could use [MVCScaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) to generate your views but in this case it uses the Models not the DB directly.

It's a slightly different way than you might be looking for but it is still worth a look to help you as you look at this.